# TensorFlow: Parse a string into two tensors

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a TFRecord dataset where each record contains 19 uint8s followed by 36 bytes representing 9 little-endian float32s.

The first 19 bytes is the examples,the last 10 floats are the label. I just want to reinterpret these bytes accordingly.

Tensorflow doesn't like it when I index a string like this:

```
def parse(serialized):
    return tf.decode_raw(serialized[0:19], tf.uint8), tf.decode_raw(serialized[19:], tf.float32)
```

> *** ValueError: Index out of range using input dim 0; input has only 0 dims for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [],
>   [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[3] = <1>.

Next, I tried to interpret the serialization as bytes and then reinterpret the slices:

```
def parse(serialized):
    expanded = tf.decode_raw(serialized, tf.uint8)

    return tf.cast(expanded[0:19], tf.uint8), tf.cast(expanded[19:], tf.float32)
```

This works for the uint8s, but for the float32s, it's interpreting each byte as its own float32:

```
(Pdb) sess.run(label_it)
array([205., 204., 204.,  60., 154., 153., 153.,  60., 102., 102., 166.,
        61.,  10., 215.,  35.,  60., 184.,  30.,  45.,  63.,  51.,  51.,
        51.,  61., 133., 235.,  81.,  61.,  92., 143.,  66.,  61., 164.,
       112.,  61.,  61.], dtype=float32)
```

I just really want to split this string into two pieces between the 19th and 20th byte, and then decode it. But I'm having a heck of a time with it. At this point I'm interesting in hearing any solution, however hacky, for doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Heh, I think asking this question helped me clarify the question to myself, and I was able to find an answer. My answer is [`tf.strings.substr()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/substr)

```
def parse(serialized):
    example_str = tf.strings.substr(serialized, 0, 19)
    label_str = tf.strings.substr(serialized, 19, -1)

    return tf.decode_raw(example_str, tf.uint8), tf.decode_raw(label_str, tf.float32)
```

But I'd love to see a better way posted.